# Interpreter backend, how do you traverse your abstract syntax tree?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on an interpreter and have not found a good explanation of how to traverse and abstract syntax tree after semantic analysis. I wondering what the correct way to do it is. I understand that you merge terminals into their parents processing from left to right and repeat this as much as you can.

I have this abstract syntax tree, which may or may not be correct.

[image: ast]
<sub>(source: [theadesilva.com](http://theadesilva.com/so_1.jpg))</sub>

What do I do?

merge 34 and 3 into *, then merge 4 and * into +, then merge ident into call and + into call? Is that right? What is a good algorithm to traverse a tree backwards like that?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do a direct AST interpretation without transforming it into something reasonable (like a flat stack VM bytecode) first?

Comment: Maybe because (s)he doesn’t know any better? Maybe never heard of a flat stack VM bytecode or doesn’t know it’s benefits?

Answer (score 1):

I would not have built the AST as you did. I would view print as a function with one argument. So I would build the tree as

```
print
     \
      +
    /   \
   4     *
       /   \
      3     34
```

You walk the tree and evaluate the children before you apply the operator/function in the root to the children. There is no rule that says you can only have two children. If you need several you can have several children.

i.e. fun(a,b,c,d)

```
    fun
  / / \ \
 a b  c  d
```

or no children

i.e. currentTime()

```
currentTime
```

so for your question with my AST it would be

```
visit                                               
print          need to evaluate right child  
+              left is 4, need to evaluate right  
*              left is 3, right is 34  
               evaluate 3 * 34 and return right = 102  
               evaluate 4 + 102 and return right = 106  
               evaluate print, so print 106
```

Comment: Relatistically, PRINT number *should* be a function.  There's little reason to wire it into the base language (he likely will have to write "PRINTCHARACTER" or "PRINTSTRING" into the language, but PRINT number should be something that generates the digit string and then invokes a primitive to print).  I would have build the tree the way the OP did.  That doesn't really change the answer, except it adds an extra step: after evaluating the arithmetic, he has "call(print,106)" and executes his interpreter step for "call", which finds the AST for print (somewhere) and starts to evaluate that.